# Deleting values and splitting values from single column to multiple ones in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column named `STREETNAME` where I have data based on this model: `townName`, `streetName`, `1` where `1` is the number of a house of a certain `streetName`. How do I delete `townName` from the whole column and also put numbers of houses into a separate column named `STREETNO`?

Comment: Hi Aleksander, welcome to SO, just for clarification, finally you want are the columns `streetName` and `STREETNO` ? If it is so then what will happen if there are same `streetName` for different `townName` ?

Comment: The goal is to leave only `streetName` in it and to put number of the house to a separate column

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `regexp_substr()`.  This seems like the simplest method in Oracle to split a string with components separated as commas:

```
select regexp_substr(streetname, '[^,]+', 1, 1) as town,
       regexp_substr(streetname, '[^,]+', 1, 2) as street,
       regexp_substr(streetname, '[^,]+', 1, 3) as num
from (select 'town, street, 123' as streetname from dual) x
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also capture leading/trailing whitespace around each component?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(STREETNAME, '^[^,]+, (.*)$', '\1') AS STREETNAME_NO_TOWN,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(STREETNAME, '^.* (.*)$', '\1') AS STREETNO
FROM yourTable;
```

The above alias `STREETNAME_NO_TOWN` would only remove the town name (which is what your question asked for), thereby leaving the street and number.  If instead you want to isolate only the street then use this:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(STREETNAME, '^[^,]+, ([^,]+),.*$', '\1')
```

Comment: Sometimes I have weird numbers like 10-2 or 5-b-7 and in this case it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! Sometimes I have names of houses instead of numbers so they carry over to the column dedicated to street number. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: I strongly suggest that you take a few moments and show us some sample data.  Leaving comments like this is not the best way to get help on this site.